# Python ECDSA Same Public Key(generated with ecdsa.VerifyingKey) Does not verify

Tags: python, cryptography, ecdsa

If i generate public key directly from signing key with  `sk.get_verifying_key()`

It works fine and verifies it,but if i try to manually create public key with `ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string` for some reason it does not verify it and returns false.

copy paste following code and run you will observe the strange difference

```
import random
import string
import sys
import ecdsa
import hashlib
import binascii

# randomly generate secret and public keys
sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.generate(curve=ecdsa.NIST256p, hashfunc = hashlib.sha256)
pk = sk.get_verifying_key()

publicKeyVerifyObject = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string(bytes.fromhex(binascii.hexlify(pk.to_string()).decode('utf-8')), curve=ecdsa.NIST256p)

print("public key:", binascii.hexlify(pk.to_string()))
print("public key:", binascii.hexlify(publicKeyVerifyObject.to_string()))

# a message to sign
name = "lastpeony"

# signature of the message
signature = sk.sign(name.encode('utf-8'))


#first test
try:
    print (publicKeyVerifyObject.verify(signature, name.encode('utf-8')))
except ecdsa.BadSignatureError:
    print (False) 


#second test
try:
    print (pk.verify(signature, name.encode('utf-8')))
except ecdsa.BadSignatureError:
    print (False)
```

What i expect is True True output from both tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were missing `hashfunc = hashlib.sha256` in `publicKeyVerifyObject`, the default is `sha1`.

Try

```
publicKeyVerifyObject = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string(bytes.fromhex(binascii.hexlify(pk.to_string()).decode('utf-8')), curve=ecdsa.NIST256p, hashfunc = hashlib.sha256)
```

The results:

```
public key: b'659ee7dcc3905b7be2969ec1c09824d81d85f54202865eeee3e5a950f585d092b90727759bded7caad24825a501e6e4bf2cb05726d9a153de7a3cc3a58ccc7c7'
public key: b'659ee7dcc3905b7be2969ec1c09824d81d85f54202865eeee3e5a950f585d092b90727759bded7caad24825a501e6e4bf2cb05726d9a153de7a3cc3a58ccc7c7'
True
True
```